# MYSQL Timestamp field inserting NULL values

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have a table with the below column

```
  `update_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

I have two databases set up using replication. On master while inserting null to the above column, Current time stamp is inserted.

But the same record on being replicated to the slave gives error. *Error is that Null value is not permitted for the column*

The only difference is that in slave DB, the specific column is indexed in the table.

Mysql reference has the below line

```
By default, TIMESTAMP columns are NOT NULL, cannot contain NULL values, and assigning NULL assigns the current timestamp.
```

So i expect the column to get the current time stamp

The data is put to master through spring.

Is this an expected behaviour?

Comment: "while inserting null" what do you mean? Show the insert statement. Are you passing null and you expect it to become current_timestamp automatically?

Comment: Its inserted as "null".
INSERT INTO table Values(null);

Comment: well that's forbidden, due to the not null requirement: my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

The `NOT NULL` is permitting you to pass a null value which would normally become `current_timestamp`.

**Original**

> Its inserted as "null". INSERT INTO table Values(null);

That's forbidden due to the `NOT NULL` requirement (the point with `NOT NULL` is to forbid null values) -- you're not suppose to mention the value. Skip the value and the default value will take it's correct place.

Let's take a look at the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

> In addition, you can initialize or update any TIMESTAMP column to the current date and time by assigning it a NULL value, **unless it has been defined with the NULL attribute to permit NULL values**.

You are permitting null values because of your `NOT NULL` requirement. In order for your argument to be valid then you need to remove it.

Comment: I have updated the question. Mysql reference permits passing null values to timestamp fields.

Comment: "The NOT NULL is permitting you to pass a null value which would normally become current_timestamp."
Because of this data is inserted to master. My question was why the same insert fails to a replicated DB.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The flag

```
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
```

was not set in replication. Setting this solves the problem